# How do I add up one column and divide by the count on another matching column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to add up the revenue of one column, and divide it by appropriate groupings of another column.

So I would be getting revenue totals by country. In Column A are revenue numbers and column B lists what country that revenue is from. One caveat is that it is per transaction. So there can be an arbitrary number of listings for any country.

How would one do that?

Thank you!

Comment: can you use pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on PNuts answer:

`=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"China",A:A)`

Give you your results.

I would take it one step further and make C a list of all countries you are interested in and then make D:

`=AVERAGEIF(B:B,C1,A:A)`